# How to add custom sliders UI in blender to change the material properties of a collection and also drive an animation using drivers?

Tags: python, animation

In the pics below Animagraffs has added custom slider UI where he can change the transparency of an object within a collection by changing the value of the alha of the material. He also drives the animation of a mechanism using custom sliders. Can someone please explain how he is doing it and how to write the codes for creating such a UI.
YouTube link: https://youtu.be/T7Hb8kRUHEI?si=p9qFqT_rk1I2013k
Refer 9:58 mins where he explains a little bit about how he controls the transparency

Refer 22:00 mins where he explains the animation part[image: refer this imageenter image description here for the custom slider UI]

Comment: That looks like the [Dope Sheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/dope_sheet/index.html#dope-sheet) editor, and those are probably keyframable animations

Comment: But how to bring this sliders in the dopesheet?

Comment: i think you should focus on one question only (you asked at least two) because that's the rule of this site. Both mechanism aren't too hard to code - so first thing you should do (if you don't know, you should start learning it): learn python and learn how to use the Blender API. honestly, if you know it a bit, it shouldn't be to hard to do what he did.

Comment: Apologies for asking two questions. I am a newbie. Can you elaborate a bit on how to write the code or provide me with any resources where i can learn this.